# $x^2+y^2+2axy=0 \Rightarrow x=0$ and $y=0$

Tags: proof-writing, quadratics

Show that for all real numbers $x$ and $y$, for all $-1<a<1$
$$x^2+y^2+2axy=0 \Rightarrow x=0 \text{and} y=0$$
I see that $x^2+y^2+2axy=(ax+y)^2+x^2-(ax)^2$.

I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

Given $$-1 \leq  a \leq  1\Rightarrow -2xy \leq 2axy \leq 2xy\Rightarrow x^2+y^2-2xy \leq x^2+y^2+2axy \leq x^2+y^2+2xy$$

So we get $$(x-y)^2\leq x^2+y^2+2axy \leq (x+y)^2$$

Now Given $x^2+y^2+2axy=0$

So we get $(x-y)^2\leq 0$ and $(x+y)^2\geq 0$

So thses two condition are simultaneously hold when $(x-y) = 0$ and $(x+y)=0$

So we get $x=y=0$

Comment: A can't be 1 or -1 so it will be (x-y)^2<0 and (x+y)^2 ...

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(x+ay)^2=x^2+2axy+a^2y^2$.

\begin{align}
(x+ay)^2&\ge0\\
x^2+2axy+a^2y^2&\ge0\\
x^2+2axy&\ge-a^2y^2\\
x^2+2axy+y^2&\ge y^2-a^2y^2\\
x^2+2axy+y^2&\ge y^2(1-a^2)
\end{align}
Now, if $-1<a<1$, then $a^2<1$ and $0<1-a^2$. Also, unless $y=0$, $y^2$ is always positive. Thus, unless $y=0$, the right-hand-side of the above is positive, and:
\begin{align}
x^2+2axy+y^2&\ge y^2(1-a^2)>0\\
x^2+2axy+y^2&>0
\end{align}
Thus, unless $y=0$, the left-hand-side cannot equal $0$.

If $y$ *does* equal zero, then $x^2+2axy+y^2=0$ implies $x^2=0$ and thus $x=0$. Thus, if the expression equals zero, then $x=0$ and $y=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x=r\cos(\theta)\,\,\,\,,\,\,\,y=r\sin(\theta)\\ \Rightarrow\,\, r^2(1+asin(2\theta))=0$$
if $\,\,\,r^2\neq 0\,\,\,$ we have $\,\,\,1+asin(2\theta)=0\,\,\,$ that is impossible, so $\,\,\,r^2= 0\,\,\,$and we have$\,\,\,x=y=0$.

Comment: I didn't understand ! Can you explain more how did you get that sin and cos

Comment: it's a usual polar changing of variables.

Comment: What is r ? Is it radius of the trigonometry circle

Comment: you have not hear anything about polar coordinate? google it.